# How to check duplicate data in my datastore and display the error?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Am working on GAE,GAE datastore and  python.

This is my dbmodel.py,

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty(required=True)
    email = db.EmailProperty(required=True)
```

this is my main.py,

```
class AddCustomerHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):         
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('template/addcustomer.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):     
        input_fullname=self.request.get('fullname')
        input_phone=self.request.get('phone')
        input_email=self.request.get('email')

        newcustomer=Customer(name=input_fullname,phone=input_phone,email=input_email)

        self.redirect('/addcustomer')
```

Data store is working fine. I want to check the my `newcustomer` data duplicate or not based on fullname. if its already entered the data didn't allow to save and need to display the error message.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's good Unique model available in webapp2:

> For example, suppose we have a model `User` with three properties that
>   must be unique across a given group: `username`, `auth_id` and
>   `email`::
>
> ```
> class User(model.Model):
>     username = model.StringProperty(required=True)
>     auth_id = model.StringProperty(required=True)
>     email = model.StringProperty(required=True)
> ```
>
> To ensure property uniqueness when creating a new `User`, we first
>   create `Unique` records for those properties, and if everything goes
>   well we can save the new `User` record::
>
> ```
> @classmethod
> def create_user(cls, username, auth_id, email):
>     # Assemble the unique values for a given class and attribute scope.
>     uniques = [
>         'User.username.%s' % username,
>         'User.auth_id.%s' % auth_id,
>         'User.email.%s' % email,
>     ]
>
>     # Create the unique username, auth_id and email.
>     success, existing = Unique.create_multi(uniques)
>
>     if success:
>         # The unique values were created, so we can save the user.
>         user = User(username=username, auth_id=auth_id, email=email)
>         user.put()
>         return user
>     else:
>         # At least one of the values is not unique.
>         # Make a list of the property names that failed.
>         props = [name.split('.', 2)[1] for name in uniques]
>         raise ValueError('Properties %r are not unique.' % props)
> ```

This is the only way to transactionally check the uniqueness.

https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#Unique

Comment: Thank you Dmitry Sadovnychyi