# GAE NDB model sequential ID

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to create ndb entities with their IDs growing sequentially ...
Like 1, 2, 3... n

I wont mind if one or two ID miss in between .. like 
1, 2, 4, 5 .. n (3 missing)

What is  the simplest way of doing it ?

Comment: Is there a risk of race condition? I.e. two entries created at once?

Comment: Yes there is a rate possibility when two user hit the same spot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820133/how-to-check-duplicate-data-in-my-datastore-and-display-the-error/29820563#29820563

Comment: I was looking for something other than transactions