# Avoid duplicate entries in Datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I am trying to send the data to google app engine in python using Webapp2, But when I check the entries in the data in console I found duplicate entries which means except Id everything is same.I want to avoid those duplicate entries.Please suggest me if there is anyway to find the duplicate values to avoid.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use custom ID for each entity you create.

Comment: Dup. Google s.o. for this. Also Include attempt and whats not working.

Comment: A trivial s.o. search shows many clear answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820133/how-to-check-duplicate-data-in-my-datastore-and-display-the-error

Answer (score 2):

Hash the entities and use the hash value as the key for your Entity.

Comment: Sounds dirty but smart. How exactly does this work? Seeing as a Key does not only consists of a string

Comment: IMO you can find a serialization approach with the properties required to be unique and hash that value ...

Comment: Sure, but how would you 'convert' that to a Key is what I meant to ask

Comment: in java : KeyFactory#createKey("MyKind", myHashValue);